# SysReq key not working when trying to reboot

Tags: reboot

My Ubuntu 20.04 freezes sometimes, and been trying to reboot it with "Alt+PrintSc+reisub", but nothing happens. I was holding down Alt while pressing the reisub.
My /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq was 176, I set it to 1, just to try it out, but this is not the problem.
I have two real questions and a stupid one:

1. How do I know that printscreen is my sysreq button?
2. If it is not, how do I find it?
3. Is it a problem that I don't use capital letters?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alt + sysrq + REISUB doesn't reboot my laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop)

Comment: Are you using the HWE? or GA kernel?  (ie. which kernel stack are you using; Ubuntu LTS releases offer two stack choices)  **Capital letters are not an issue**; but I've had issues last few (13+) days with SysRq combinations on *impish* / 5.13 and haven't yet worked out why the change.. I've not had issues with released software. but do note on some keyboards, extra keys are required (which often include a Fn key too)...   I just booted a *focal* system & SysRq works perfectly for me (*but I don't know your used stack so didn't look to see what mine was*)

Comment: On some laptops Fn maybe be needed, so try `Alt+Fn+PrintSc+reisub` .

Comment: Nmath, No it does not, that is why I posted this question.

Answer (score 0):

1. printscreen is **ALWAYS** SysRq. On some laptops (like mine), you might see that the Page Down button (PgDn) has another label in orange or blue which says SysRq. Pressing this button with the Fn key will achieve the same results as pressing Print Screen. In fact, in gnome, it will take a screenshot of the entire screen.
2. It is.
3. No, it should work by just pressing the letter without holding shift or having Caps Lock turned on.

But to solve your problem, first of all, does pressing Print Screen while you desktop is not frozen take a screenshot? If it doesn't your keyboard type might be a non standard one which needs to be changed (but I highly doubt it). Or it might be that that button is broken. Or if the button has another label on it too, you might need to hold Fn while pressing it.

But if it does, make sure that your alt button is working properly. If both of them work, then I'm stumped.