# Ubuntu 23.10 hangs on shutdown with manufacturers logo

Tags: shutdown, 23.10

**Summary** - my system hangs on shutdown with Ubuntu logo and manufacturers logo. Doesn't matter how long I wait. Fans remain on. Only way to restart is to press and hold power button for many seconds. Shutdown (suspend) blanks the screen and never recovers, but sleep after period of inactivity works fine.

**System** Dell Precision Tower 3420 Xeon e3-1270 v5 x 8 cores 32GB RAM Nvidia Quadro K1200 graphics. Latest updates on Ubuntu 23.10 booting from NVMe SAMSUNG 512GB. TP-Link Archer T4U v2 [Realtek RTL8812AU] Wifi on USB. ASUS USB-BT500 on USB.

- Dual boot Windows 10 (select through BIOS boot options rather than grub). Installed on SATA spinning rust which boots and shuts down normally.
- Boot from Live Fedora 37 USB works fine -- (kernel 6.2??, is this a 6.5 problem?)
- Boot from Live Ubuntu 23.10 USB also fails to shutdown properly.

**I've tried** the following -- all to no avail:

1. Removed quiet splash from boot options - nothing unusual. Gets all the way to final shutdown message without displaying errors
2. Checked `journalctl -rb -1` after rebooting. Gets all the way to the journal close message without errors
3. Shut down graphics first `systemctl stop gdm.service` and then `sudo shutdown` -- system hangs. Same if I boot to command line and shutdown -- system hangs
4. I had to manually install drivers for the Wifi & Bluetooth -- but this isn't the problem because neither installed for Live 23.10 USB and still hangs
5. I've updated the BIOS to the latest

I'm a bit stuck for ideas -- any help most welcome?

Comment: Try a different kernel?

Comment: Did some reading: added ppa:cappelikan/ppa, downloaded mainline and installed 6.5.7 (latest). Didn't fix the problem. I also found this bug report https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=217995 which says there is a patch to resolve my problem (Dell bios bug). Is in 6.6-rc6 and also 6.5.8 so either I have to wait or work out if possible to add the patch

Comment: In the meantime you can try Alt+SysRq while you hold the keys down with your other hand type REISUO (shutdown) or REISUB (restart). There is some information in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/11002/alt-sysrq-reisub-doesnt-reboot-my-laptop)

Comment: Good tip - I was only vaguely aware of Sysrq-REISUB and that's a really good explanatory post you referenced. RESISUB works a treat for restart, but unfortunately, REISUO just hangs my machine - so I have no good shutdown option just yet.

Comment: The latest 6.6.1 kernel fixes this problem

Comment: I had similar issue with Ubuntu 24.04 dev branch, my running kernel was 6.7.2. After upgrading to 6.7.3, this issue is solved.

Comment: I tried 6.7.3 which requires a bit of jigging around because installing the kernel fails if any drivers are loaded through dkms (6.73 doesn't support dkms). Removing dkms drivers allows the kernel install to complete and then <drumroll>... suspend works correctly. However... with no dkms -- I can't run the proprietary nvidia 535 drivers (because it uses dkms) which means I have to put up with glitchy graphics and fans running at high speed with the Nouveau.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is fixed in the latest kernel 6.6.1

... but the system still can't suspend.

So it does fix the shutdown hang but suspend doesn't work (due to ACPI bug in BIOS)