# How to use Magic SysRq Key, if theres no SysRq key on my keyboard

Tags: sysrq

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

According to this it's very important.
What I can do?
Can I rebind this key to something else?

Comment: SysRq is usually the PrtScrn button

Comment: You don't have any <Print Screen> key on your keyboard? Could you post a picture of your keyboard or give us the model? I have a German and a Spanish keyboard here, both have the key but of course it's named differently: “Druck”, “S-Abf” and “ImpPt”.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/4401/how-do-i-use-reisub-with-an-apple-slim-aluminum-keyboard

Comment: It doesnt have any. Its USA layout ten-keyless keyboard

Answer (score 3):

As ravery said, your "Print Screen" key should work.

"SysReq" is often not spelt out on small laptop keyboards, but it is still that key.